# How to get HTML5 video to take up full height and width of browser window?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html5-video

I need the video to take up the full width and height of the browser on first page load, I am using bootstrap. How do you achieve this?:

The following code kind of does it, but the height is more than 100% of the browser. I want to be able to scroll down to the text underneath, so the video is only showen at the top.

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ifusion/pen/EgPNdG)

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 }

#homepage-video {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <video id="homepage-video" autoplay="true" loop="true" >
   <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"
     type="video/mp4" />
         Your browser does not support HTML5 videos.
       </video>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
        // Text in here....
   </div>
```

Comment: You'll have to provide some more details. I tested this locally and it behaves as expected. Perhaps Bootstrap is adding additional styles and you need to `!important` on `height`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it via jquery, Just include a jquery library and add below code

```
$(function(){
    $('video').css({width:$(window).width(), height:$(window).height()});
});
```